Nonlinear FiniteElement method (`Inactive`-form) : PDE-Discretization fails
In the documentation Nonlinear Finite Element Method Verification Tests an analytical solution of the problem is given
solu = DSolve[{D[u[x]^2 D[u[x], x], x] + 4 == 0 , u[0] == 1, 
u[1]^2 u'[1] == 2}, u, {x, 0, 1} ][[1]]
{D[u[x]^2 D[u[x], x], x] + 4 == 0, u[0] == 1} /. solu // Simplify

As an example for nonlinear Finite Element Method I would like to numerically confirm this solution {u -> Function[{x}, (1 + 18 x - 6 x^2)^(1/3)]} :
ode = Inactive[Div][-u[x]^2 Inactive[Grad][u[x], {x}],{x}] - 4 == 
NeumannValue[2, x == 1] 
U=NDSolveValue[{ode, DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0] }, u, {x, 0,1},"InitialSeeding"->{u[x]==1} ]

Last command only  evaluates with option InitialSeeding
Finally I' m looking for the  FEM-matrices, but
NDSolve`FEM`ProcessPDEEquations @@ U  

doesn't return a result , instead error message "NDSolve`ProcessEquations::dsvar: {1.,1.23529,1.39932,1.52764,1.63366,1.72411,1.80288,1.87246,1.93455,1.99037,<<31>>} cannot be used as a variable." which I don't understand.
As a workaround I tried
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1, x]] 
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
     "Space"} -> {{u}, {x }}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {mesh}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{u[x]^2 }}, 
   "MassCoefficients" -> {{0}}, "LoadCoefficients" -> {{-4}}];
bcdata = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, 
   sd, { {DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0]  , 
     NeumannValue[2, x == 1 ]} }];
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, 
  sd]; 
dbc = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcdata, mdata, sd];
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = dpde["All"];
 DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness}, dbc];

too,  but the resulting nonlinear stiffness matrix has only one non-vanishing element stiffness[[1,1]]==1 .
What is the correct way to get the final PDE-discretization, which should depend on the unknown node values of function u[x]?
Thanks!

At the very minimum you need at lease one call to DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd, "Nonlinear"] otherwise only the stationary components are build.

@user21 Thanks, I didn't know the option "Nonlinear"

Have a look at the documentation - it helps ;-)

NDSolveFEMProcessPDEEquations[{ode,
DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0]}, u, {x, 0, 1},
"InitialSeeding" -> {u[x] == 1}] works just fine.

@user21 Is option "Nonlinear" introduced in Mathematica version >12.2?

It's not an option. It's an argument. I don't think so. But it seems I have forgotten it on the DiscretizePDE ref page. Have a look at FEM Programming tutorial nonlinear section

Yes, indeed the "Nonlinear" parameter was forgotten on the ref page (but is shown in the above mentioned documentation). I have added that parameter now and it will show in the next version (14.1) in the documentation ref page of DiscretizePDE.

Also careful: NDSolveFEMProcessPDEEquations will give you the stationary matrices. The matrices have to updated in the nonlinear solution process explained in the documentation above.

@user21 Thank you for your helpful comments!
